# Equivalent to 'w' in Vim to next non alphanumeric character?

Tags: vim

I was wondering if there is a single key (like '`w`') that specifies "*from the current cursor position to the next non alphanumeric character*".

This is the scenario: In the example below, with the cursor under 'e', I want to delete the 'example' word (between underscores):

```
this_example_word
```

With the cursor under 'e', if I press `dw`, i delete `example_word`, not `example`. I know that I can do `dt_`, but I was wondering if Vim has a "word" concept that implies only a-zA-Z0-9, so that I can press `dX` o `cX` and delete/replace only `example`.

Best regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vim` treats a sequences of `[A-Za-z0-9_]` or sequences of non-blank characters separated with white space as a *word*, sequences of non-blank characters separated with white space as a *WORD*. You can re-define what *word* mean to `vim`:

```
set iskeyword-=_
```

Now place your cursor at `e`, press <kbd>d</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> or <kbd>d</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't know that underscore was the ONLY special character appart from :alpha: ... Thanks a lot for your answer, now works as expected.

Comment: I found a problem with the above solution. Now Vim doesn't consider "in_array" a PHP keyword... so it also affects to syntax highlighting, not only to the "definition of word" for w, W, b and B ... any idea?

Comment: @sromero: Maybe you should define a function to toggle adding/removing `_` from `iskeyword`.

Comment: @sromero: You can read [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=ja&fromgroups#!topic/vim_dev/aptsKXTwCwo) for some ideals.